# using equals or instanceof in toString

Tags: java, clone, equals, tostring, instanceof

Ok guys I have a program with a 'MartianManager' class: *Note code is not complete still have some missing pieces just supplied entire code for reference of somewhat how it is going to look when complete

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MartianManager {
private ArrayList<Martian> martians;
private ArrayList<Martian> teleporters;

public void addMartian(Martian m) {
    martians.add(m);
    if(m instanceof GreenMartian)
        teleporters.add(m);
}
//public Object clone() {

public Martian getMartianClosestToID(int id) {  
}
public void groupSpeak() {
    for(Martian m : martians) {
        m.speak();
    }
}
public void groupTeleport(String dest) {    
}
}
```

and Martian class:

```
public abstract class Martian implements Cloneable {
int id;

public Martian(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return super.clone();
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public boolean equals(Object o){
    return this.getId() == ((Martian)o).getId();    
}
public abstract void speak();

public String toString(){
    String str = "";
    if (this instanceof GreenMartian) {
        str = "Green martian" + id;
    }
    if (this instanceof RedMartian) {
        str = "Red martian" + id;
    }
    return str;
}       
}
```

it is extended with GreenMartian:

```
public class GreenMartian extends Martian implements ITeleport{

public GreenMartian(int id) {
    super(id);
}
public void speak() {
    System.out.println(id + "Grobldy Grock");
}
public void teleport(String dest) {
    System.out.println(id + "teleporting to " + dest);
}

}
```

also extended with RedMartian:

```
public class RedMartian extends Martian {

public RedMartian(int id) {
    super(id);
}
public void speak() {
    System.out.println(id + "Rubldy Rock");
}
}
```

I actually have a few questions , but for now my question is in the toString of the Martian class. It should return a string like this: "Red [or Green] martian" +id. I need to determine the type of Martian, I started to use the instanceof but like this "Martian couldn't be resolved to a variable". I'm trying to determine if this would be the best way or if an equals() would be the best way to determine the type?

Also this is my first time using "clone" so not sure how it works exactly, but had a thought is there a way to determine what the "clone" was and determine it that way?

Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 5):

No

```
public String toString(){
    String str;
    if (Martian instanceof GreenMartian) {  
}
```

in `abstract` `Martian` class is a bad idea. You don't want your parent class to depend on its children.

Implement a `toString()` method in each subclass instead and **let polymorphism do its work**.

---

If you absolutely have to

```
if (Martian instanceof GreenMartian) {
```

is wrong. You use `instanceof` as so

```
instanceOfClass instanceof SomeClass
```

In this case you get a reference to `instanceOfClass` with the `this` keyword, since you are calling the method on an instance

```
this instanceof GreenMartian
```

Comment: Ok that makes sense, I've updated my code with instanceof. Is this the way it should look, or could it be simplified any more?

Comment: @user2745043 No, no. Check polymorphism in wikipedia and you will get it

Comment: @user2745043 It is syntactically correct (assuming your imports are correct), but an extremely bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not have a parent class reference any classes that extend it.  This is bad practice (and might not actually work, i haven't tested).  You should really just override the toString function in each extended class.

```
public class GreenMartian extends Martian implements ITeleport{

    public GreenMartian(int id) {
        super(id);
    }
    public void speak() {
        System.out.println(id + "Grobldy Grock");
    }
    public void teleport(String dest) {
        System.out.println(id + "teleporting to " + dest);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
         return "GreenMartian: whatever info you'd like to include.";
    }

}
```

Now, if you want to have a similar format for all subclasses, you have two options.  One is to call the toString method of the parent class, and prepend that to the subclass's toString method.

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return super.toString() + "GreenMartin: info.....";
}

//The parent toString could look like this:
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "Martian( ... put any parent class info here, id ect)";
}
```

The final output for a GreenMartian toString call then may look like this:

```
Martian(id:23) GreenMartian(planet:greenburg)
```

A Third option would be to have a common string format in the parent class.  For example, in the parent class, include this attribute:

```
protected static final String format = "Class: %s, id: %s, info: %s";
```

Then, in the subclass toString, you can do this:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format(format,this.getClass().toString(),id,myInfo);
}
```

Comment: Ok so if I used your first example and just override the toString for each sub class how would it look in the parent class? Iv'e never used 'format' so I'm not sure if it would be the same in the first one too.

Comment: The toString of the parent class can really look however you want it to.  It should probably contain any info that the parent class holds, and in a format that makes it obvious. I'll update my example.

Comment: Ok that's what I was thinking, since I'm overriding the toString in the subclasses, nothing in the parent toString is even going to show up anyways correct?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct.  Note though that you can call the parent method of an overridden method by using 'super'. This give you access to the parent toString if you really wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String name = this.getClass().getSimpleName()` to get the name of your class. Then you can check `name.substring(0,1).equals("G")` or `name.substring(0,1).equals("R")` to detect Red or Green.

Comment: This is really bad OO design.

Comment: This is really bad OO design *and* inefficient. Why going to create sub-strings and calling `equals` on them to compare just a single `char`? Why not `name.charAt(0)=='G'`? Too obvious?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, it should be `if (this instanceof GreenMartian)` - but IMHO whenever you are tempted to use such an downcast (upcast??), it is an sign of bad OO design. Rather write a specialized `toString()`method for your martians.  And you should really check for `o==null` in your `equals()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Martian is not a variable. Try this instead:

> if(this instanceof GreenMartian)

Comment: although you're right - please don't do this. See Sotirios'/aglassman's answers and use polymorphism.

Comment: totaly true, but he wanted to know why Martian couldn't be resolved to a variable